# URL Match Regex: Positive and Negative terms

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match both negatives and positives terms in a URL match regex.

"Word1" and "Word2" are negatives ones, and "Word3" is the positive. The URL must have the positive keyword and dont have the negatives to match.

https://example.net

https://example.net/word3 - match

https://example.net/word3/word2 - dont match

https://example.net/word3/word1 - dont match

Currently I'm excluding the homepage too, but with the positive match I think that it will be unnecessary.

```
^((?!(word1|word2|http(s?):\/\/example\.net\/?($|[?#][&=#+%0-9a-zA-Z]+$))).)*$
```

How can I use positive and negative matchs in just one string?

Comment: What language or tool are you using? I think you'll want to use [positive & negative lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (if the order doesn't matter), but they aren't implemented by every regex engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If positive [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are supported, you could use:

In your example you use both exemple and example but I have used example here.

`^(?!.*\bword[12]\b)(?=.*\bword3\b)https?://example\.net/word\d.*$`

That will match:

- `^` Assert start of the string
- `(?!.*\bword[12]\b)` Negative lookahead to assert what is on the right is not `word1` or `word2`
- `(?=.*\bword3\b)` Positive lookahead to assert what is on the right is `word3`
- `https?://example\.net/word\d` Match start of the url followed by /word and a digit.
- `.*` Match any character 0+ times
- `$` Assert end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YtNL6A/1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it resolved my problem! I edited my question correcting 'exemple' to 'example'..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(?=.*word3)(?!.*word(?:1|2)).*$
```

It starts by matching the `start` of string, then uses a positive `look ahead` for `'word3'`, then uses a `negative look ahead` for `'word'` followed by either 
1 OR 2.

Finally it matches the rest of the string (if it has passed the test).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!